# How to use Bootsrap4 for particular tag only

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gridview

**Hello Peeps**

Thanks a lot for taking your time in reading this. I am new in Wordpress. I want to update my footer.

I wrote an HTML code for my footer which I was going to use on Customisation>Layout>Footer. 
But I am unable to link bootstrap 4 with that as the code window automatically removes the linked bootsrap line,

So I tried to add a footer widget but it is affecting my whole page. I want to use bootstrap 4 to make my footer responsive. 
I don't know how to use media libraries. I managed to make my footer responsive with grid system (col-sm-12 , col-lg-4) but whenever I import my bootstrap 4 link.

Can you please help me on how should I make my footer responsive?

If you want to check it live 
You can see footer of this page : https://techdevio.com/about/
Do not check footer of homepage as it is made by thrive architect and I was just trying to replicate it by writing code.
If you have any suggestions on how to make that code responsive without using bootstrap I would appreciate that too. :)

Thanks In Advance

```css
.bg {
  background-color: rgb(49, 65, 140);
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#social {
  margin: 60px 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social {
    margin: 26px auto;
  }
}

#social ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

#social li {
  margin: 0 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #social li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#social li a {
  color: black;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

.category {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Literata !important;
  font-size: 19px !important;
  --g-regular-weight: 400;
  --g-bold-weight: 700;
}

.cat-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Muli;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>



</head>

<body>

  <footer class="bg">
    <div class="container pt-3">

      <div class="row">


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <a href="https://techdevio.com/" class="footer-logo">Tech Dev I/O</a>
          <p>Tech Dev I/O Keeps You Updated With Latest Tech News & Gadgets. We Also provide Reviews Of Trending Gadgets </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <p class="category">Information</p>


          <p><a href="https://techdevio.com/contact" target="_blank" class="cat-2">➤ Contact us</a></p>

          <p><a href="https://techdevio.com/about" target="_blank" class="cat-2">➤ About us</a></li>

            <p><a href="https://techdevio.com/privacy-policy/" target="_blank" class="cat-2">➤ Privacy policy</a></p>


        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <p class="category">Contact Us</p>


          <p> <a href="tel:+918999817454" class="cat-2"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> +91 89998 17454</a></p>
          <p><a class="cat-2" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pune,+Maharashtra/@18.5245649,73.7228812,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bc2bf2e67461101:0x828d43bf9d9ee343!8m2!3d18.5204303!4d73.8567437" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                             123, Society, Pune, MH 440013</a></li>
          </p>

          <p>
            <a href="mailto:techdevio20@gmail.com" class="cat-2" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>  techdevio20@gmail.com</a>
          </p>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/techdevio.io">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/TechDev17">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/techdevio/">Instagram</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a target="_blank" href="https://in.pinterest.com/techdevio/">Pintrest</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="social" style="margin-top: 0px;">
      <p>&copy;2020 Tech Dev I/O</p>
    </div>


  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply stylesheets for specific HTML tags. You can scope them, for example - make all rules in the stylesheet related to the given tag/selector:

```
footer.bg {
 /* Some footer styles */
}
footer.bg .category{
 /* Some footer category styles */
}
```

but these styles are applied globally. Whenever the rule is matched, its styles are applied accordingly.

In your case, from what I understand, you need the Bootstrap grid tools like `col`, `row`, etc., but the import of the whole Bootstrap CSS overrides and breaks the styles you already have on that page.

There is an official Bootstrap grid CSS, which will provide only those responsive grid utilities. Keep in mind that it also comes with some display and flexbox utilities as well, which may potentially clash with some of your styles if you happen to use the same classes.

Here's the link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css

Comment: Hello @Dimitar, 
Is there any specific css which I can write just for 

footer.bg {

}
which will make my code responsive for desktop and mobile and tablet? 
If yes Where can I find that?